# How to share Firebase Realtime Database reference between activities and broadcast receivers?

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

Developing my first android application with Java. The flow of the application is that when it starts it configures geofences if they have not yet been initialized (for example the first run of the app). Subsequently one of those geofences would do the work of dynamically loading the nearest 99 points. The main activity and the broadcast receiver would both need to request information from the database about the points. How do I achieve this without using significant amount of bandwidth for requests?

So far I've created a Database class file to help with requesting data but I am not sure which event listeners to use for the data. If I use **onDataChange** then how can I share that database reference between the main activity if the app is run and broadcast receivers for geofences?

Comment: What have you tried so far in code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.